# How would Vaatu look like if he emerged out of an avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I was wondering and this is probably silly, but say for example, 10,000 years is up and there is another Avatar in that generation when Vaatu is about to emerge again inside Raava.

Is it going to be like attached to the Avatars body or Raava's (Spirity body) inside of that current Avatar?

This might be somewhat speculative (?) but I was wondering if there was anything canon that could support/go against this scenario in some way.

Comment: I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I mis-read this as "Klaatu" and was coming here to needlessly say; "Gort. Klaatu, barada, nikto. Klaatu, barada, nikto." Also, some smart remark about how in the re-make, Keanu Reeves should have been cast as Gort, not Klaatu, because his performance was so robotic.

Answer (score 3):

This is speculative as there is no clear answer to your question, but I would guess that he will re-emerge from the Avatar in the same fashion he emerged from Unalaq, when he successfully ripped Raava from Korra. From the mouth.

[image]